# ATTiny85 wont turn on, not sure how to debug

Tags: microcontroller, programmer, troubleshooting

The ATTiny85 in the below circuit refuses to do anything.

```
$ avrdude -c usbtiny -p attiny85
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.    
avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

My setup:

- Programmer: USBTiny ISP (Verified it works with an ATTiny with 0.1" pins in a breadboard that I could program just fine)
- Environment: avrdude via OSX
- Programmer interface: 6 header pins shoved into 6 pin ISP plug and inserted into offset programmer holes

I've verified:

- ATTiny chip is mounted in the correct orientation, the dot lines up where it should.
- Positive voltage (~4V from LiPo) exists between `VCC` and `GND` pins on the chip.
- All traces from the ISP holes to the chip pins are connected where they should be.
- Ceramic oscillator contacts connect with correct pins, and it's `GND` is grounded.
- I can't find any shorts between discreet traces.

I've done everything I can think of and everything checks out. Except that my USBTinyISP programmer cannot talk to this chip. It acts as the programmer pins are not connected to anything.

Lastly, a previous iteration of this board seemed to work fine. That older board didn't include the LiPo charging circuit and it connected the ISP `5V+` pin to the power line (which shouldn't be required if the battery is powering the circuit).

- Could my chip be bad?
- What are the chances the ATTiny85 cap was put on backwards?

I'm out of troubleshooting ideas. What am I missing?

[image: Project Schematic]
[image: Project PCB]
[image: Project Photo]

Comment: Decoupling capacitors are conspicuous by their absence...

Comment: Indeed.  You might also try a new 't85 that has never been fused to depend on an external resonator.  Once it has, it can't be programmed without a working clock.  Beware that programming with 5v signals while supplying less is out of spec (and I have *seen* it cause damage) - though you may be able to fix that with series resistors as long as there is little on-board liading.  It's probably worth modifying a board for external power as a test anyway - and beware of mistreating lipos.

Comment: @Majenko, Indeed. Embarrassingly enough, I'm not sure when or where I would use decoupling capacitors. But the previous version of this board seemed to require no such thing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton this chip was virgin from a Mouser strip of parts. I'm not sure what the default fuses are (cause I can't read them), but I imagine they would default to the internal clock, right?

Comment: You can probably retrofit some smt caps on the prototype where power nets are on adjacent pins, such as your connectors.

Comment: If you have a resonator in your design, you are presumably fusing for it, so your programming process could (partially) work once off the default internel clock fuses and fail thereafter - perhaps you could have overlooked that trial.

Comment: Setting the fuses was the first thing I was trying to do. But avrdude just coughs up `avrdude: initialization failed` when I try to do anything at all, including setting fuses. And if it has an external oscillator, it should repond to the programmer no matter the fuses because it's got an oscillator anywhere it could be configured to use, right?

Comment: Does the oscillator run? You probably need a 10x probe to tell.  Realistically, your circuit is simple enough that you can point-to-point a dip to that board, or an soic to a proto board dip adapter inside an hour and factor out the differences from your previous.  Also, since you are playing with smt, drop the $100 on an import hot air rework - it will be well worth it.

Comment: I lack the tools to find out I'm afraid. Unless there is a way I use a multimeter? Only thing I'm sure of is that the contacts connect to the right pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had a bad chip! I swapped out the ATTiny85 with a spare and it booted right up. Weird. Perhaps the DOA rate of these chips are higher than I expected, or maybe I static discharged it somehow?

No idea, at least I'm glad I didn't miss something silly :)

Comment: It may the fuse programming.

Comment: Yes, most likely corruption of the fuses from a previous attempt.  Though applying higher voltages than the supply to the pins - as you seem to be doing here - can also cause damage.

Comment: Are you saying that using a fully charged LiPo at 4.2V and then using 5V logic form the programmer can cause damage to the chip? If so, I guess that's a good reason to connect the 5V power pin from the programmer to the chip, to bring the supply voltage up to match the logic voltage?